Why does width of the ImageView not change after being rotated 90 degrees?
I am making an version of monopoly in javafx and I am adding tiles which are extend the Stackpane class. This works for all types of 'tiles' except for one, the simplest type of tile, imageTile which just contains an imageview and an image that should perfectly fit but after rotating this tile the width is way to big and this width corresponds to the width before rotating.
So this is my class in which ImageTile extends RectangleTile which extends Stackpane. Now look at the Tile that says Schamper,
the only thing I do with this tile otherwise is add it into the bigger gridpane.
public class ImageTile extends RectangleTile{

    Map<String,String> ImageNameToName = Map.of("utility1","Schamper","utility2","Urgent FM");
    String imageName;
    Image image;
    public ImageTile(String imageName,int pos) {
        super(pos,"");
        this.imageName = imageName;
        
        image = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/be/ugent/objprog/ugentopoly/assets/"+imageName+".png"),118,66,true,true);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setRotate(90*(pos/10))
        getChildren().add(imageView);
    }
    ...
}

What am I doing wrong here?


See the "layout bounds" table in the layout documentation. The layout bounds of an image view do not include any transforms (such as rotations) applied to it. The layout bounds of a Group, however, do include transforms applied to the group's child nodes, so if you wrap the image view in a group, it will work as desired. I.e. just replace getChildren().add(imageView) with getChildren().add(new Group(imageView))
